# How do I pick the correct answer on a subjective question?

Tags: discussion

I have recently asked a subjective question and the answer that got the most votes is not really the answer I prefer.

However it being a subjective question logically I should accept what the majority agree on.

Can any subjective question be accepted since there is, by its own definition, no definitive answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I pick the answer I like the most. My question, my choice.

Answer (score 3):

Apply whatever criteria you use to determine the correct answer to this question to find the answer to other subjective questions.

Answer (score 2):

For any non-trivial problem, there is more than one solution which is "correct" in any sense of the word. So more than one answer may be correct but SO only allows you to flag one as correct.

In this case, I don't hesitate to vote any good answers up.

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

You pick mine. :)

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong. You pick **mine** .

Comment: You guys are both being a bit too subjective in your approach here. I've objectively determined that my subjective opinion is objectively correct, and as such should be accepted, always.

Answer (score 1):

One of my pet peeves about Stack Overflow is that questioners seem to feel compelled to accept the most popular answer.

You asked the question, and you should accept *your* preferred answer, regardless of the majority consensus.

Future readers will decide for themselves whether they prefer the accepted answer, the most popular answer, or maybe a completely different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the answer that was most helpful to you. The community answer will always be right below it. That's the way things are supposed to work. Even if you select what is currently the highest voted answer, there's no guarantee that will always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing as you asked the question, go for the answer **you** feel helps you the most.

Answer (score 0):

> However it being a subjective question logically I should accept what the majority agree on.

I beg to differ.

Personal bias is a necessary evil when you seek subjectivity. (BTW: This is a totally subjective viewpoint ;-) If the answer that got the most votes do not reflect your personal bias, you should not really be bothered. Fine, you don't follow the herd!

However, a good yardstick to keep the bias in check is logic. I'd try to have that around.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "your choice" is correct, you are after all the subject, but I'd prefer to see the question left open for the benefit of later readers.

Answer (score 0):

> .*..However it being a subjective question logically I should accept what the majority agree on....*

Mmmmm nope!, You don't have to "accept what the majority agree on"  Otherwise, would you jump over the window if everyone in the room shouts:

*"DO IT!,DO IT!,DO IT!,DO IT!,"*

?

If there is not a clear answer that satisfy you, then don't pick any. If there is one answer to **your** question, just pick it evn if it has -5 downvotes.  But even better, try not too ask too many [subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ask subjective questions to begin with